# Как удалить активность?

Tags: android

Приложение запускается и появляется активность **A**(начальная активность). Нажав некую кнопку в активности **A** , попадаем в активность **B**. В активности **B** , есть кнопка , для возвращение в активность **A** (в функции кнопки использовал Intent). Нажимаем кнопку и попадаем в активность **A**, то есть на начальную активность. Далее нажав Назад , попадаем в активность **B**. Мне не хотелось бы попадать в активность **B** при нажатии Назад , а выйти из приложение. Как это можно сделать?

**Что я сделал?**

Допустим мы в активности **B** , в которую попали из **A**. Нажав кнопку в **B** , мы попали в активность **A**. Последняя функция которая сработала у **B** была `onStop()` . В этой функции я вызвал **onDestroy()** , чтобы её удалить. Но приложение вывело ошибку.

Comment: Если "в активности В" для возвращения в "активность А" использовать не Intent, а Назад, то в "активности А" нажатие Назад уже никак не вернёт в "активность В". Ну так, чисто из общих соображений...

Comment: Вам не нужно удалять активити,  нужно работать со стеком переходов или с флагами запуска активити. Даже если активити удалить, то при обращении к стеку переходов (нажатии кнопки Назад) она будет опять загружена. `onDestroy()` - метод жизненного цикла, который вызывается **системой**, когда происходит уничтожение активити, чтобы программист мог выполнить какие-либо действия при наступлении этого события, сам он ничего не удаляет и вызывать его принудительно (в обход системы) черевато проблемами

Comment: я думаю finish() и intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); тебе поможет, только вот в твоем случае у тебя будет висеть 2 А активити, та с которой ты начал, и та которую ты создал из Б

Comment: Там где вы прописываете `intent` для чего вы его прописываете? Используйте `finish()` вместо `intent` в активити В и по нажатию кнопки НАЗАД в активти А приложение будет закрываться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы нажимаете в Б кнопку и попадаете на А, то это не там А с которой вы попали в Б. В вашем случае запускается новый экземпляр активити и стек активити выглядит так A -> Б -> A. Соответственно при нажатии назад он раскручивается в обратную сторону. Вам в активити Б надо просто вызвать `finish()`, а не запускать новую активити.

Ещё советую почитать про стек активити и задачи в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html?hl=ru)